# What is the security issue in this code?

Tags: java, security, interview-questions

I was asked how this code has a security risk.  Does anyone have any ideas what it is? I am new on the security topic and don't know what to look for.

```
String DBdriver = "com.ora.jdbc.Driver";
String DataURL = "jdbc:db://localhost:5112/users";
String loginName = "stackoverflow";
String passwd = "codeReview";
Class.forName(DBdriver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DataURL, loginName, passwd);
String Username = request.getParameter("USER");
String Password = request.getParameter("PASSWORD");
int iUserID = -1;
String loginUser = "";
String sel = "SELECT UserID, Username FROM USERS WHERE Username = '" 
    +Username + "' AND Password = '" + Password + "'";
Statement selectStatement = conn.createStatement ();
ResultSet result = selectStatement.executeQuery(sel);
if (result.next()) {
       iUserID = result.getInt(1);
       loginUser = result.getString(2);
}
PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter ();
if (iUserID >= 0) {
       wr.println ("you logged in: " + loginUser);
} else {
       wr.println ("you cannot login in !Access Denied!")
}
```

Comment: I guess you're not acquainted with little [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 9):

Off the top of my head:

1. Those parameters don't seem to be escaped before being stitched into a query (opening up SQL injection attacks)
2. The database seems to be keeping passwords in plaintext rather than as salted hashes (which is an especially bad combo with the previous point)

You'd really want to

- escape the username and password before dropping them into a `SELECT` statement
- keep the password stored as a hashed value at minimum (you'd then want to verify the users' input by hashing the password you get from them and comparing that to what you have stored). Ideally, you'd [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) them too.

It wouldn't hurt to accept the login info as a `POST` parameter either (just to reduce the number of logs username/password combos would end up in).

Comment: how can i escaped to prevent sql injection, any example?

Comment: @Kit Ho - Sorry, not my language. SQL-related functions/methods tend to be available everywhere though; check the docs rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Rather than escaping parameters, I would use [setNString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @KitHo: OWASP provides a cheat sheet with some sources, but you should also review their top 10 for self-education: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 3):

Some other notes:

1. Don't mix naming styles:

   ```
   String DataURL = "jdbc:db://localhost:5112/users";
   String loginName = "stackoverflow"
   ```

   [Variable names should be `camelCase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082729/to-camelcase-or-not-to-camel-case) (with lowercase first letter).
2. Instead of checking that `iUserID` is `-1` or not check the result of `result.next()` and set a `boolean` flag:

   ```
   final boolean hasUser = result.next();
   if (hasUser) {
       iUserID = result.getInt(1);
       loginUser = result.getString(2);
   } else {
       wr.println ("you cannot login in !Access Denied!");
   }
   ```

   Or even better:

   ```
   final boolean hasUser = result.next();
   if (!hasUser) {
       wr.println ("you cannot login in !Access Denied!");
       return; // etc.
   }
   final int userID = result.getInt(1);
   final String loginUser = result.getString(2);
   ```

   It removes magic strings from the code and makes it easier to read.

   Note that I moved the variable declarations too. (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables* has a good overview on this topic. (Google for "minimize the scope of local variables", it's on Google Books too.))
3. Instead of the `ResultSet.get*(int columnIndex)` methods use the `ResultSet.get*(String columnLabel)` ones:

   ```
   userID = result.getInt("UserID");
   loginUser = result.getString("Username);
   ```

   It also removes some magic numbers from the code and makes it easier to read.
4. This:

   ```
   PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter ();
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter();
   ```

   (From [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141388.html#475)):

   > Note that a blank space should not be used between a method name and
   >   its opening parenthesis. This helps to distinguish keywords from
   >   method calls.
5. I'd use longer variable names for readability:

   ```
   PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
   ```

Comment: so is that the main insecure issue is that the SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Inaimathi. I haven't found any more security issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues, from least to greatest.

1. The connection info to the database is in your code.  Should be in a
   separate configuration file so that it can be changed and the
   developer doesn't need to know the production password.  Depending
   upon the setup (single dev does dev and dba for instance), this may
   not be a big issue.
2. SQL injection vulnerability, a username of '; drop table users; -- might just 
   ruin yor day.
3. You are storing the users password in plaintext.  You should never store the users 
   password, you should be storing a hash of the users password.  Users recycle
   passwords.  If you store the  password, and your system is hacked (or you have 
   a disgruntled employee), that can be used to access their other accounts.  Such a
   breech might open your employer to a great deal of liability...
   Because this effects multiple systems, it is the most serious.